# How long a thread will be alive in java?

Tags: java, threadpool

I create a thread using

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
```

You start a thread using t.start(); 
Now how long the thread will be alive?
To what state it will go after X (the answer of above question) seconds?

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Threads");
}
```

What will happen if the thread has run() method?

Comment: That thread is kind of a bad example because it doesn't execute anything, ie. the body of the `run()` it executes is empty. It will start and end right away.

Comment: [**How to search on Google**](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en)

Comment: Your thread isn't doing anything, so the answer comes down to scheduling delay. A thread that needs to actually do something will live approximately until its job is done.

Comment: are you mixing a question on ThreadPools?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread created and started exactly as you describe will be alive only for as long as the empty `Thread.run()` method takes to do nothing and return. When the thread terminates, the `t.isAlive()` function will return `false`.

Normally, a thread does something useful and will be alive for as long as the `run()` method has not returned.

Comment: So will the thread state  be dead after running the run method?

Comment: If you're specifically asking about the return value of `Thread.getState()`, then it will return `Thread.State.TERMINATED`. Java does not use the word "dead" when referring to thread states.